# Errors with WPAchemy on upgrade to WordPress 3.6

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes

I've been using the [WPAlchemy](http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/) class to create meta-boxes in WordPress, and this has been fine until I upgraded to WordPress 3.6.

With the upgrade, I've suddenly started to get the following errors:

```
Strict Standards: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method WPAlchemy_MetaBox::_global_head() should not be called statically in /wp-includes/plugin.php on line 406

Strict Standards: Non-static method WPAlchemy_MetaBox::_is_post() should not be called statically in /wp-content/wpalchemy/MetaBox.php on line 1352

Strict Standards: Non-static method WPAlchemy_MetaBox::_is_post_or_page() should not be called statically in /wp-content/wpalchemy/MetaBox.php on line 986

Strict Standards: Non-static method WPAlchemy_MetaBox::_get_current_post_type() should not be called statically in /wp-content/wpalchemy/MetaBox.php on line 1024

Strict Standards: Non-static method WPAlchemy_MetaBox::_is_page() should not be called statically in /wp-content/wpalchemy/MetaBox.php on line 1352

Strict Standards: Non-static method WPAlchemy_MetaBox::_is_post_or_page() should not be called statically in /wp-content/wpalchemy/MetaBox.php on line 1005

Strict Standards: Non-static method WPAlchemy_MetaBox::_get_current_post_type() should not be called statically in /wp-content/wpalchemy/MetaBox.php on line 1024
```

These errors appear whether or not I actually create any meta-boxes.

A few other people seem to be having the same problems, but I haven't been able to find a solution (other than disabling error reporting, which isn't really a solution). Unfortunately, this is beyond my rather basic PHP skills.

Comment: I've not found a solution to this problem yet, but I have noted that if I roll back my PHP version from 5.4.10 to 5.2.x the errors no longer show.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I have created a workaround on this. 
Here's some help: http://www.pirenko.com/blog/2013/10/17/wpalchemy-warnings-fix/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This makes sense, but it's a lot of code that needs to be changed so it would not work pasting it here. Anyway, I'll keep that in mind on eventual future replies here.

Comment: Either way, I suggest that you add some relevant information, such as what the workaround does, and how the author (in this case I assume that's you) did implement it. Adding more information may lead more people to click the link and test the work around you've mentioned. And Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

While patch linked by Pirenko is working it's definitely not the best approach to solve the problem as the patch author simply adds duplicate code and avoids using standard WPAlchemy methods.

Also that patch was somehow causing issues to plugin Im working on, so I took the pain to actually fix WPAlchemy related strict notices myself. Here are the changes:  https://github.com/mch0lic/wpalchemy/commit/d53216953b1e0f761c6b2f94da257a638f85aa8a

Note I'm not sure if moving add_action hooks to constructor is acceptable as I'm not really familiar with WPAlchemy and its workflow, but even after the change WPAlchemy related code is working so does my plugin.

Comment: Just in case anyone comes across this question, I should note that the latest version of WPAlchemy appears to have fixed the problem.